# React-Bootstrap accordion panel group not working when children are components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accordion, react-bootstrap

I have a problem where I have a panelgroup and its children are components which render a panel. [image: React DOM] When the panels are direct children of the panelgroup everything works fine. But when I try to render the panel inside a component and add that to the panelgroup, nothing expands when you click on the header. Looking at the react DOM, I can see that the event key does change when I click the headers though...
The parent...

    `return (
      <PanelGroup
        accordion
        activeKey={this.state.activeKey}
        onSelect={this.handleSelect}
        id="papers-table"
      >
        <PaperItem key={paper.id} paper={paper} eventKey={1} />
      </PanelGroup>
    );`

And the child...
`return (
      <Panel
        eventKey={this.props.eventKey}
        style={{ "borderColor": Colors["DARK" + this.props.paper.decision.toUpperCase()] }}
      >
        <Panel.Heading
          style={{ "backgroundColor": Colors[this.props.paper.decision.toUpperCase()] }}
        >
          <Panel.Title toggle>{this.props.paper.title}</Panel.Title>
        </Panel.Heading>
        <Panel.Body collapsible>
            {this.props.paper.abstract}
        </Panel.Body>
      </Panel>`